# Query to find connected components in mongodb graph collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graph, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to group the connected component in the mongodb collection.
Example:

`{ '_id': 1, 'data': '...', 'similar_id': [2,3,4] }`

`{ '_id': 2, 'data': '...', 'similar_id': [1] }`

`{ '_id': 3, 'data': '...', 'similar_id': [1,4] }`

`{ '_id': 4, 'data': '...', 'similar_id': [1,3] }`

`{ '_id': 7, 'data': '...', 'similar_id': [2,3,4] }`

`{ '_id': 5, 'data': '...', 'similar_id': [6] }`

`{ '_id': 6, 'data': '...', 'similar_id': [5] }`

Diagram for above network.

[image: Graph Network for above example]

So I want a query which can find connected components.

`{ '_id': ..., 'groups': {[1,2,3,4], [5,6], [7]} }`

The result may not need to look like above but only in some form such that they are separated in different groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ain't pretty but this is what I got, a brief description of my strategy was initially creating two groups of nodes. one contains node that are "connected" (i.e both x=>y and y=>x edges exist). and the other are potential single nodes. meaning they had one or zero of the x=>y or y=>x edges.

Once achieving this all we have to do is reducing the array by connecting connected nodes.

Mind you I fully believe this is not the "best" way to achieve the result you want as I just focused on getting it done without over thinking about performance or redundancy. with that said I'm define myself as a Mongo enthusiast and I would definitely say I struggled with this a little. For me this is usually a red flag that says my schema or db solution is wrong (maybe use a graph db?). Again these are just my opinions and it's entirely possible I just tangled myself with this pipeline.

It's worth mentioning I considered an approach using [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) however on a fully connected or nearly fully connected graph this has a required depth usage of `n` where `n`=number of node, eventually I decided against it although thi approach might viable if you have any prior knowledge that can limit the depth to a certain constant.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$similar_id",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      similar_id: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$similar_id",
          "$_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1,
      similar_id: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      tmpId: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gt: [
              "$similar_id",
              "$_id"
            ]
          },
          [
            "$_id",
            "$similar_id"
          ],
          [
            "$similar_id",
            "$_id"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tmpId",
      sum: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      single: [
        {
          $match: {
            sum: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$_id"
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            potentionals: {
              $addToSet: "$_id"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      clusters: [
        {
          $match: {
            sum: 2
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            edges: {
              $addToSet: "$_id"
            },
            
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            all: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$edges",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $setUnion: [
                    "$$this",
                    "$$value"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            groups: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$edges",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $gt: [
                        {
                          $size: {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$$value",
                              as: "subgroup",
                              cond: {
                                $gt: [
                                  {
                                    $size: {
                                      $setIntersection: [
                                        "$$subgroup",
                                        "$$this"
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  },
                                  0
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        0
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$$value",
                        as: "subgroup",
                        in: {
                          $cond: [
                            {
                              $gt: [
                                {
                                  $size: {
                                    $setIntersection: [
                                      "$$subgroup",
                                      "$$this"
                                    ]
                                  }
                                },
                                0
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "$setUnion": [
                                "$$this",
                                "$$subgroup"
                              ]
                            },
                            "$$subgroup"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      $concatArrays: [
                        "$$value",
                        [
                          "$$this"
                        ]
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$single",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$clusters",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      groups: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$clusters.groups",
          {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$single.potentionals",
                  as: "pot",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      {
                        $size: {
                          $setIntersection: [
                            [
                              "$$pot"
                            ],
                            "$clusters.all"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      0
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              as: "single",
              in: [
                "$$single"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TY1ufntz0Rm)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for such late reply, but maybe other will find this useful.

You can try using NetworkX library in Python.

1st unwind similar_id to have documents with pairs `{'_id':1,'similar_id':2}`

```
import networkx as nx 

unwind={'$unwind':'$similar_id'}
pipeline=[unwind]
cursor=db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
G=nx.Graph()
for c in cursor:
      G.add_edge(c['_id'],c['similar_id'])
    
    
all_clusters=list(nx.connected_components(G))  # a list of all connected components
len(all_clusters) # number of connected components
```